# PHP stmt prepare fails after multiple queries

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in on line 64

I've found multiple other posts with this problem, but the solutions I've tried haven't made a difference.
Things like `stmt_close()` or `stmt_free()` didn't make a difference.

So here is my actual code snippet:

1st prepare and execute:

```
// Connect to database
$mysqliID = mysqli_connect($mysqliHost, $mysqliUsername, $mysqliPassword);
if (!$mysqliID) throw new Exception("");
if (!mysqli_select_db($mysqliID, $mysqliDB)) throw new Exception("");

// Check if the username or email address aren't already accupied.
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqliID, "SELECT id FROM Account WHERE username=? OR email=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $email);
if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) throw new Exception("");
$duplicates = 0;
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $duplicateid);
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
{
    die ("error:-gebruikersnaam of email al in gebruik.");
}
```

2nd prepare and execute:

```
// Save account with salted and hashed password.
include "PasswordHash.php";
$hashResult = create_hash($password);
$hashResultSplitted = explode(":", $hashResult);

$salt = $hashResultSplitted[2];
$hash = $hashResultSplitted[3];
$verified = 0;
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqliID, "INSERT INTO Account (username, hash, salt, email, verified) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssi", $username, $hash, $salt, $email, $verified);
if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) throw new Exception("");
```

3rd and last prepare and execute:

```
// Save verification token.
$token = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));
$expirationtime = time() + (15 * 60);
$accountid = mysqli_insert_id($mysqliID);
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqliID, "INSERT INTO Verifications (token, expirationtime, accountid) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sii", $token, $expirationtime, $accountid);
if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) throw new Exception("");
```

So in the 3rd and last block of code, I get the warning at the mysqli_prepare, but the previous two were successfully done.

---

**Solution:**
Turned out the table named Verifications should have been Verification. Found by just good reading and looking after I've had some sleep.

Comment: You should check [for errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php)

Comment: I tried that. But because mysqli_prepare returns a boolean. mysqli_stmt_error() doesn't accept my $stmt. Because it has to be a mysqli_stmt object.

>Warning: mysqli_stmt_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in on line 58

Comment: mysqli_prepare() returns a statement `object` or `FALSE` if an error occurred. - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php. If you received a boolean then the prepare failed.